# understanding error handling

Tags: c, error-handling

I can use `perror()` easily. However, I know that `strerror()` also can be used for handling. But in this code why `errnum` assigns to `errno` again? Can someone explain?

```
FILE *in;
int errnum = 0;

    in = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if (in == NULL) {
        errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", filename, strerror(errnum));
        errno = errnum;
        return 0UL;
    }
```

Comment: Evidently, the programmer is anticipating `fprintf` overwriting `errno` and wants to preserver it. Why they want to do so is not discernible from the code sample.

Comment: Actually it is not documented anywhere that `fprinf` is modifying the `errno`. Neither is `strerror`. So I don't get it either..

Comment: Ok, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391026/can-i-ever-assume-that-a-c-stdlib-function-doesnt-use-errno) might clarify it.